# AJAX Remove record from page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a php script where a query runs to load all the messages from my database.
When I click at one message I can choose delete, then he runs a AJAX call with jQuery.
At page that AJAX called there runs a query to remove the record from my database.

This is works fine. But when the AJAX call is finished, I see still the div with the message. Pass if I refresh the page the div is gone. (because I have delete it from the database).

Is it a good way to refresh the page directly after the AJAX call return `true`.
The disadvantage is that you run the database query again, and get all the data from the database.

Is there also a way to refresh the page "localy" so already loaded content is no longer be retrieved again by the database?

**EDIT :**

I have solved the problem now with:
`$('#message' + myId).remove();`

This works.

Comment: remove the element with the deleted message with jQuery too. But only after the success response of your AJAX call

Comment: Yes, that is a good solution, but i thought that there is an other way also

Comment: Can we see your jQuery that sends the ajax, and your html div?  It will only take one line of jQuery to remove the div.